# Reverse of Get Specific Version, overwrite files on server

Tags: checkin, disaster-recovery, forcing

Our source control is on a hyper-v virtual machine, and last night a snapshot-merge of the image went horribly wrong.  The source control server now contains a months-old version of the source; all changes since have been lost.

**By the way, if your source control is on a virtual machine, back up the database before you do anything with the machine image, mkay?**

I want to forcibly push my current workspace back onto the server, the reverse of doing a Get Specific Version with the "Overwrite all files" checkbox checked.

Currently, the only way I can think of to do it is to branch, delete everything, re-add everything, then merge.  PITA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will actually work, since I don't have a TFS project that I would try it on. But here is what I would try, if I found myself in your situation.

1. [tf checkout /recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw.aspx) to check out all of the files that you currently have in source control
2. [tf add /recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9yw4ea0.aspx) to add all of the files that were added over the last month
3. [tf resolve /recursive /auto:KeepYours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9yw4ea0.aspx) to handle the all the conflicts that come up.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rollback the checkin?

See the [tf rollback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx) documentation on MSDN

Comment: Um, I think you missed the bit where I said "a snapshot-merge of the image".  The virtual machine was reverted to an earlier date and all data was lost.